# L-tryptophan in mammalian cell culture

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

Why must the concentration of *L-tryptophan* be kept to a relatively ***low level*** when culturing mammalian cells?

It's an essential amino acid, so I cannot fathom why low concentrations as opposed to higher ones are best. Does it have to do with carcinogenesis or some other dangerous side effect I wonder?

Comment: It is essential but it is also not required in huge amounts. I am not sure if it has toxic effects.

Comment: I just assumed it was due to feedback regulation that would affect other amino acids' production, but I really don't know. It's a good question.